# How to create BookingList from 2 class Customer and Bus

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, structure, singly-linked-list

I am having small problems in my exercise of data. Here is the topic:

1.Input data
   Allow a user to input booking item.
   When running, the screen looks like: 
   Enter bus code:
   Enter customer code:
   Enter number of seats to be booked:

After the user enter bcode and ccode, the program check and acts as follows:
   - If bcode not found in the Bus list or ccode not found in the customer list  then data is not accepted.
   - If  both bcode and ccode are found in the booking list  then  data is not accepted.
   - If bcode and ccode found in Buses and customers lists but booked = seat then inform the user that the bus is  exhausted.
   - If bcode or ccode found and in the Bus list booked < seat and k is the entered seat then if  k <= seat - booked then data is accepted and  added to the end of the Booking list.

Somebody help me. please! < My problem is class BookingList - Booking input and maybe you can use function searchByCode >

Here is my code:

```
public class Booking {

  Customer c;
 Bus b;

public Booking() 
{
   }

public Booking(Customer c, Bus b) {
    this.c = c;
    this.b = b;
   }
}

public class Bus {

public String bCode;
public String bName;
public int seat;
public int booked;
public double departTime;
public double arrivalTime;

public Bus() {
}

public Bus(String bCode, String bName, int seat, int booked, double departTime,
```

double arrivalTime) {
        this.bCode = bCode;
        this.bName = bName;
        this.seat = seat;
        this.booked = booked;
        this.departTime = departTime;
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

```
public double travelTime() {
    double result = 0;
    result = this.arrivalTime - this.departTime;
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return " " + bCode + "\t\t" + bName + "\t\t" + seat + "\t\t" + booked + "\t\t" + departTime + "\t\t" + arrivalTime;
}

 }


 public class Customer {

public String cCode;
public String cName;
public int phone;

   public Customer()
  {
    }

public Customer(String cCode, String cName, int phone) {
    this.cCode = cCode;
    this.cName = cName;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public void displayInfoCustomer() {
    System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-10s\n", cCode, cName, phone);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return " " + cCode + "\t\t" + cName + "\t\t" + phone;
}

}
```

*/
     public class BookingList {

```
     Customer infoC;
     Bus infoB;
      NodeBooking head, tail;
    CusList cusList = new CusList();
    BusList busList = new BusList();

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
}

public void addLast(Customer c, Bus b) {
    NodeBooking p = new NodeBooking(c, b);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = tail = p;
    } else {
        tail.next = p;
        tail = p;
    }
}

public void visit(NodeBooking p) {
    if (p != null) {
        System.out.print(p.infoC + "\t\t");
        System.out.print(p.infoB);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public Booking input() {
    Validation v = new Validation();
    String cCode, bCode;
    int seat;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Customer cus = new Customer();
    Bus bus = new Bus();
    // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    Booking x = new Booking( ?,  ?);

    return x;
}

public void traversal() {
    NodeBooking p = head;
    while (p != null) {
        visit(p);
        p = p.next;
    }
    System.out.println("");
   }
}


 public class BusList {

     NodeBus head, tail;

public BusList() {
    head = tail = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
}

public void clear() {
    head = tail = null;
}

//search by bcode
public NodeBus searchByBcode(String bcode) {
    NodeBus p = head;
    while (p != null) {
        if (p.info.bCode.equals(bcode)) {
            return p;
        }
        p = p.next;
    }
    return null;
}

// delete fist
public void deleFist() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    head = head.next;
    if (head == null) {
        tail = null;
    }
    System.out.println("dele sucess");

}

// dele by bcode
public void deleByBcode(String Bcode) {
    NodeBus q = searchByBcode(Bcode);
    dele(q);
  }
}


 public class CusList {

       NodeBus head, tail;

public CusList() {
    head = tail = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
}

public void clear() {
    head = tail = null;
}

//search by bcode
public NodeCus searchByBcode(String ccode) {
    NodeCus p = head;
    while (p != null) {
        if (p.info.bCode.equals(ccode)) {
            return p;
        }
        p = p.next;
    }
    return null;
}

// delete fist
public void deleFist() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    head = head.next;
    if (head == null) {
        tail = null;
    }
    System.out.println("dele sucess");

}

// dele by bcode
public void deleByBcode(String ccode) {
    NodeCus q = searchByBcode(ccode);
    dele(q);
}
}

    public class NodeBooking {

Customer infoC;
Bus infoB;
NodeBooking next;

public NodeBooking() {
    infoC = null;
    infoB = null;
    next = null;
}

public NodeBooking(Customer infoC, Bus infoB, NodeBooking next) {
    this.infoC = infoC;
    this.infoB = infoB;
    this.next = next;
}

  public NodeBooking(Customer infoC, Bus infoB) {
    this(infoC, infoB, null);
    }
}

   public class NodeBus {

Bus info;
NodeBus next;

NodeBus() {
    info = null;
    next = null;
}

NodeBus(Bus info, NodeBus next) {
    this.info = info;
    this.next = next;
    // this(info,next);
}

NodeBus(Bus info) {
    this(info, null);
  }
}


 public class NodeCus {

Customer info;
NodeCus next;

NodeCus() {
    info = null;
    next = null;
}

NodeCus(Customer info, NodeCus next) {
    this.info = info;
    this.next = next;
    // this(info,next);
}

NodeCus(Customer info) {
    this(info, null);
    }
}
```

Please help me! I am very thankful for that